# Copy form from one project to another but resources not showing VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have two projects that I want to use the same form in.
In VB6 this was easy as I had a Common Folder for Common Code and could just add it.

I have copied the 3 files:

**form.vb**

**form.designer.vb**

**form.resx**

I then added an existing item and selected the form.designer.vb
Everything looks fine, but the 2 pictures I had are not showing even though the picture boxes are.
I can expand the arrow under **form.vb** and see **form.designer.vb** and **form.resx**
If I click on the resource file I can see my two pictures.

Why have the pictures not shown in there boxes and how do I get them back in, without importing the files again?

Comment: The resources are stored with the wrong name, using the old project's root namespace.  Just don't do this.  If you want to share classes then use a class library project.  Use the "Windows Forms Control Library" project as a best fit, just delete the user control you don't need.

Comment: Although I can programme, I'm not that o fay with VB.net and Class Stuff. I have checked the coding in Notepad for the forms and resources and can not see any reference to my old project. I am developing several project and didn't actually know I was going to share the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the Answer, or rather my dad showed me.

All I was adding was the **form.designer.vb** file, my dad showed me that if I add an existing item and select all three files during the add, it brings the form in correctly with all the resources showing in the correct place.

So I removed the form I'd added, and I added it again selecting all three forms and it now works fine and all the graphics are in the correct place.

Thanks Dad :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should put this form in a third project (a class library project), and include the new third project in the Visual Studio solution with the other two.

Comment: The thing is I had already designed it before I released I could use it in more than one project. So I am still in the same situation.